# How can I refactor my word frequency method?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

This is my method `word_frequency`.

```
def frequencies(text)
      words = text.split
      the_frequencies = Hash.new(0)
      words.each do |word|
        the_frequencies[word] += 1
      end
      return the_frequencies
    end

    def most_common_words(file_name, stop_words_file_name, number_of_word)
      # TODO: return hash of occurences of number_of_word most frequent words
      opened_file_string = File.open(file_name.to_s).read.downcase.strip.split.join(" ").gsub(/[^a-zA-Z \'$]/, "").gsub(/'s/, "").split
      opened_stop_file_string = File.open(stop_words_file_name.to_s).read.downcase.strip.split.join(" ").gsub(/[^a-zA-Z \']/, "").gsub(/'s/, "").split
      # declarar variables de file_name stop words.
      filtered_array = opened_file_string.reject { |n| opened_stop_file_string.include? n }
      the_frequencies = Hash.new(0)
      filtered_array.each do |word|
        the_frequencies[word] += 1
      end
      store = the_frequencies.sort_by { |_key, value| value }.reverse[0..number_of_word - 1].to_h
      store
    end
```

Works well, but I think I can do it better. Rubocop says my lines are too long, and I'm agree, but this is my best. Can someone explain how I can do it better?

Comment: As a first step you may wish to remove all characters other than letters, apostrophes and hyphens in compound words, and then downcase. For example,  `"I don't 'like' my sister-in-law very much. She is too blasé about everything.".gsub(/[^[:alpha:] '-]|(?<![[:alpha:]])'|'(?![[:alpha:]])/, '').downcase #=> "i don't like my sister-in-law very much she is too blasé about everything"`...

Comment: ... The regex (which with some thought you'll see is not perfect) reads, "match any character other than a letter, space, apostrophe or hyphen *or* match an apostrophe (i.e., single quote) that is not followed by a letter, *or* match an apostrophe that is not preceded by a letter". `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are *negative lookbehind* and *negative lookahead* expressions, respectively. They do not consume characters and do not form part of a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit cleaner, use multiline method chaining etc.

```
def frequencies(text)
  words = text.split
  the_frequencies = Hash.new(0)
  words.each do |word|
    the_frequencies[word] += 1
  end
  the_frequencies
end

def pre_process_file(file_name)
  File.open(file_name.to_s)
      .read.downcase.strip.split.join(" ")
      .gsub(/[^a-zA-Z \'$]/, "")
      .gsub(/'s/, "")
      .split
end

def most_common_words(file_name, stop_words_file_name, number_of_word)
  # TODO: return hash of occurences of number_of_word most frequent words
  opened_file_string = pre_process_file(file_name)
  opened_stop_file_string = pre_process_file(stop_words_file_name)
  # declarar variables de file_name stop words.
  filtered_array = opened_file_string
                    .reject { |n| opened_stop_file_string.include? n }

  the_frequencies = Hash.new(0)
  filtered_array.each { |word| the_frequencies[word] += 1 }
  the_frequencies
    .sort_by { |_k, value| value }
    .reverse[0..number_of_word - 1]
    .to_h
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be good if you just decompose the big parts. The most_common_words seems still delicate, you could explain what you're trying to do, to see what can else can be done there.

You could also make use of `frequencies`, and looking at the pattern within the method arguments, an OOP approach would fit better here.

```
def join_file(file_name)
  File.open(file_name).read.downcase.strip.split.join(' ')
end

def frequencies(text)
  text.split.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, hash| hash[word] += 1 }
end

def opened_file_string(file_name)
  join_file(file_name).gsub(/[^a-zA-Z \'$]/, '').gsub(/'s/, '').split
end

def opened_stop_file_string(file_name)
  @opened_stop_file_string ||= join_file(file_name).gsub(/[^a-zA-Z \']/, '').gsub(/'s/, '').split
end

def in_stop_file_string?(file_name, word)
  opened_stop_file_string(file_name).include?(word)
end

def filtered_array(file_name, stop_words_file_name)
  opened_file_string(file_name).reject do |word|
    in_stop_file_string?(stop_words_file_name, word)
  end
end

def frequencies_in_filtered_array(file_name, stop_words_file_name)
  frequencies(filtered_array(file_name, stop_words_file_name)).sort_by { |_, value| value }
end

def most_common_words(file_name, stop_words_file_name, number_of_word)
  frequencies_in_filtered_array(file_name.to_s, stop_words_file_name.to_s).reverse[0...number_of_word].to_h
end
```